# email for each build-step that fails in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, build, jenkins-plugins, email-ext, jenkins-email-ext

I am new to Jenkins and I would like to find a way to send an email for every build-step failure.

More specifically I have a job that runs scripts (as separate build steps) and I would like to configure Jenkins to send notifications if one of these steps fails.

Every script runs a different test-pack and the QA asked us if we can send separate emails depending on which build step is failing.

Could you please help with that?

I am already using EMAIL-EXT plugin but it doesnt seem to give you the option.

Answer (score 0):

you could put each build step in a declarative pipeline stage, as these can leverage the `post` block to send emails. Like this:

```
pipeline {
  agent { label 'docker' }
  stages {
    stage('stage1') {
      steps {
        sh 'script1.sh'
      }
      post {
        failure {
          emailext (
            subject: "Test1", body: "Test", recipientProviders: [[$class: 'DevelopersRecipientProvider']]
          )
        }
      }
    }
    stage('stage2') {
      steps {
        sh 'script2.sh'
      }
      post {
        failure {
          emailext (
            subject: "Test2", body: "Test", recipientProviders: [[$class: 'DevelopersRecipientProvider']]
          )
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that the above solution not run the entire pipeline, if, say, stage 1 fails. You could also use try/catch in a scripted or declarative pipeline. This would allow you the most flexibility (if you did, in fact, want the entire pipeline to run even if one of the steps failed, for example).